# Multi-Table GROUP_CONTACT clarification

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I have created a rextester for your use: http://rextester.com/MDHD7605

Requirements:

- Should return only 1 (single) row
- The group_concatenated should be the unique/different org data, not the same org data concatenated together 3 times.

What I'm getting is 3 rows returned, and the concatenated data is the same over and over. It should be the data from each 3 rows (of the concatenated data) into 1 column.

The GROUP_CONCAT data should be like:

> 84864-Twin Cities Spine Center-1984-1985^,99143-Hospital for Special
>   Surgery-1986-1986^^99143-Washington University-1986-1986^

What I'm getting is what you see in the preview/example link.

What am I doing wrong in my query?  And how do I correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `GROUP BY` instead of correlated subquery:

```
SELECT genealogy_users.imis_id, genealogy_relations.user_id
       ,genealogy_relations.relation_type
       ,genealogy_users.home_page
       ,GROUP_CONCAT(genealogy_orgs.org_id,'-',genealogy_orgs.org_name,'-',genealogy_relations.start_year,'-',genealogy_relations.end_year,'^') 
          AS org_list
FROM genealogy_users 
JOIN genealogy_relations ON genealogy_users.imis_id = genealogy_relations.user_id 
JOIN genealogy_orgs ON genealogy_relations.org_id = genealogy_orgs.org_id 
WHERE genealogy_users.imis_id = '00003'
GROUP BY genealogy_users.imis_id
        ,genealogy_relations.user_id, genealogy_relations.relation_type
       ,genealogy_users.home_page
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/RWEC74366)**

Comment: Thank you.. this gives the results I was looking for.  How/where can I add an ORDER BY to oder by the end_year col/data?

Comment: @whispers `ORDER BY` goes as last clause in query.

Comment: Thats where I did add it:  ORDER BY genealogy_relations.end_year

But it had no effect on the order of the concatenated data.

Comment: @whispers Ok, so I guess you won't to sort data inside [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat). Put it there.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the assist!  * Can you also add WHERE clauses to the GROUP_CONCAT?  (its not needed,. just trying to make the 'lesson' complete)

Comment: @whispers Nope, you cannot filter inside GROUP_CONCAT (at least not easy). If you have specific case please ask new question.

Comment: Fair enough (just wasnt sure, no real case scenario where it was needed, just going off your previous suggestion or my clarification)

Working Rextester for others:

http://rextester.com/HIWTXT38751